# AJAX content Type issues

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why this ajax call is not working? When I change it to `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, which has the semicolon in between?
The source code can be tested via below url. try to test it.
https://jsfiddle.net/rrcjdv6e/7/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService/HelloWorldWebService.asmx/Test",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#divResponse").show("slow");
        $("#divResponse").css("background-color", "green");
        $("#divResponse").css("color", "white");
        $("#divResponse").css("text-align", "center");
        $("#divResponse").css("margin", "20px");
        $("#divResponse").text(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public string Test()
{
    return "Hello World " ;
}
```

Comment: you need to return data in json format

Comment: where is your ajax closes braces? `})`

Comment: Given that you're returning a plain string, have you tried `$("#divResponse").text(response);`? Also you can improve the script by caching the `divResponse` selector, and making a single `css()` call.

Comment: edited, I forgot to place braces. but the problem still here.

Comment: In your case, do not set contentType as you are not sending any data. And dataType must be 'text' as the returned data would be that.

Comment: It is not work by removing the content type, my question is why remove the semicolon in between, the ajax call is not working probably. Some ajax calls do not need the semicolon.

Comment: The semicolon I removed is in the content type
  "application/json; charset=utf-8" to 
 "application/json charset=utf-8"

Comment: some codes are in https://jsfiddle.net/rrcjdv6e/1/, except the hello world webservice call don't know how to put it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `contentType` and `dataType` attribute from the Ajax call. By default, the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService/HelloWorldWebService.asmx/Test",
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        $("#divResponse").show("slow");
        $("#divResponse").css({
            "background-color": "green",
            "color": "white",
            "text-align": "center",
            "margin": "20px"
        });
        $("#divResponse").text(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your WebMethod, you need to return json data, or else change dataType to text